# How can I get rid of a weird mistake category named “smart_label_root_name” in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I dragged an email to Games Category but accidentally let go of the left mouse button. The Gmail added that weird category. I tried to delete it but that in the screenshot happens all the time.

[image: Weird Label]

Comment: Does https://support.google.com/mail/forum/AAAAK7un8RUglp05CBr61M/?hl=en help?

Comment: @captcoma The key answer on that link is “This same thing happened to me! To get rid of it, I loaded the basic HTML version and deleted the label from there.”